# Qt-Based Application binary compatiblity issue due to glibc version

Tags: linux, qt, glibc

I am developing and building my QT-based application on ubuntu 12.04 LTS which uses glibc 2.15. The binary version of the application runs on some linux distributions but not on others. One of the main problem is compatibility issues caused by different versions of glibc with different linux distributions. For example, it doesn't work on centos which uses glibc 2.12 or wary pup which uses glibc 2.10.

Is there anyway to build QT against a lower version of glibc on ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Or do I have to switch to a lower version of Ubuntu to do all the devleopment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way to support old glibc is to build the applications on a older setup.

I have no problem building a complex Qt application (including the use of QtWebKit) on CentOS 5.8 (with gblic 2.5). The application runs fine on Ubuntu, as old as 8.04 (Hardy Heron).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am now building my app on ubuntu 10.04.